# Define Class in Typescript can't get property

Tags: typescript

When I define a simpe `Class` below, I think there is no simpler `Class` than this

```
class Greeter {
  greeting: string;
  constructor(message: string) {
    this.greeting = message;
  }
}

let greeter = new Greeter("world");
```

But, when compile this code, the terminal will call error error `TS2339: Property 'greeting' does not exist on type 'Greeter'.`

I have no idea about this error...

This is my `tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strictNullChecks": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "es7"
    ]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "lib",
    "es"
  ]
}
```

Comment: You code compiles just fine. Are you sure you are getting the error in the  code posted or did you skip some lines?

Comment: This error message is in the terminal, when I compile my code. I have seen that the code is running correct. But how can I skip this error message?

Comment: It should not throw an error message in the first place if you are compiling the above code.

Comment: But it still throw this error message. Is anything wrong in my tsconfig.json?And my typescript version is 2.4.2

Comment: Could you create a test project where only the code above is used? I agree with @Saravana that the code you showed is correct and shouldn't throw any errors. A quick way to check it is the [Playground site](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=class%20Greeter%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20greeting%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20constructor(message%3A%20string)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20this.greeting%20%3D%20message%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20greeter%20%3D%20new%20Greeter(%22world%22)%3B).